# Firefox keeps asking me if I want to deactivate flash (on websites that don't have flash content)

Tags: firefox, adobe-flash, manjaro

I am running the latest version of firefox and manjaro 64 bit, and the latest, old version of flash because there aren't other options.

I have been using Linux for like 10 or more years, and the following never happened. Firefox is asking me if I want to activate flash on virtually every website that I visit, including live.chess.com, which has nothing but a Java chess board. I run ad blocker so no flash ads.

I know I can press allow and remember and then firefox would stop asking, but this is unexplainable. Besides, it warms me of potential risks, I press on the link "what are the risks", it takes me to Adobe flash download page.

I don't know, something seems fishy, I have never ever felt that my computer is infected with a virus, but today I feel that way. I can't explain why firefox is asking me if I want to activate flash, even on pages that doesn't have flash content, and never received that many pop ups from firefox on that subject before.

I can't scan my pc, because all the antivirus are either old versions or useless, or paid version. Even Clamav, I've never seen it detect a virus in my life, and I guess it scans for windows viruses not Linux. I know that all OS might get infected, but I just think that all Antivirus available for linux are useless, IMAO. and the chances of my pc getting infected are super low because I am obsessed with security.

Is it a bug in the new Firefox?

[image]

Why would Mongo DB download page have flash content? Why would I see this warning?

Comment: Check this article out: https://threatpost.com/mozilla-disables-flash-in-firefox/113763 - it said that Firefox would keep blocking Flash 'til the security bugs got fixed.  And hey, how could you be sure that Mongo DB doesn't include any code that needed Flash to run?

Comment: @McSinyx i can by looking at the source code, and even if it does have flash, I'm 100% that live.chess.com doesn't; thx for the article btw

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firefox has now unblocked Flash, but only if you install the latest plugin:
http://www.stream-entry.ca/2015/07/updating-flash-plugin-for-firefox-on.html

Comment: This doesn't explain why you'd get the error on a page with no flash, which is what the question is about

Comment: This does not answer he questions raised in the first post, yet gets selected as the best answer. I feel like I wasted both my time and effort.

Comment: @dakka actually your answer does not answer the question, it only explains why i see what i see on mongodb, and I was the first to upvote your answer, **McSinyx**'s comment is what really answers the question, why this weird behavior by firefox, but since it's just a comment, i picked the answer that fixes the problem. Future users will admire an answer that fixes their problem, rather than answer telling them that mongodb website uses flash. I know that **dcamero** isn't well formatted per SE standards but we all were newbies, let the guy enjoy his time here, as long as he's not posting shit

Comment: @dakka and 7 upvotes gives u more rep than an accepted answer, you definitely didn't waste your time.

Comment: Yea thats ok, sorry was a little annoyed, points and rep dont matter. Apologies...lol

Answer (score 7):

The download page does actually have flash in it, which is why firefox is detecting it. I found this as an example:

https://www.mongodb.org/static/bower_lib/zeroclipboard/dist/ZeroClipboard.swf?noCache=1437010946839

Type: application/x-shockwave-flash

That was on their download page here: https://www.mongodb.org/downloads. If you want to check that yourself, right click on the page and then click on `view page info` then click on `Media` at the top. Then click on the first item and use the arrow keys to go through each one. You will see the location and type etc below, eventually you will come across the one I linked above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice trick. But can you find Flash on http://live.chess.com/ ? The OP said there is.

Comment: I cant seem to get there, i guess I need an account. But yea there are currently vulnerabilities in flash that are being rectified check this news post: http://www.developer.com/daily_news/firefox-chrome-disable-support-for-flash.html